# C++ implicit conversion constructor call

Tags: c++, gcc, constructor, copy-constructor, implicit-conversion

Why does gcc required copy constructor for implicit conversion constructor call?

```
class X
{
public:
        X(int q) {}

        ~X()
        {
                std::cout << "~X()" << std::endl;
        }

        X(const X&) = delete;
};

X x = 1; // gives error: use of deleted function ‘X::X(const X&)’
```

What is more interesting here that if I even write copy constructor it is not called. Destructor is called only once, so the following code

```
class X
{
public:
    X(int q) {}

    ~X()
    {
        std::cout << "~X()" << std::endl;
    }

    X(const X&)
    {
        std::cout << "copy ctor" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    X x = 1;
}
```

prints `~X()`

Is it bug? Is there any workaround?

gcc version on my locaL PC is 4.6.3, this also works the same way on another gcc version (online)

http://ideone.com/ustDRj

Comment: It is not a bug, it is called [*copy elision*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision). The compiler is allowed to elide copies under certain circumstances. It still requires that the copy constructor(s) be available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`X x = 1;` is the syntax for *copy initialisation.* In case the initialiser is not of type `X` (as here), this is semantically equivalent to this:

```
X x(X(1));
```

That is, it constructs an insance of `X` from argument `1`, and then copy-initialises `x` from that instance.

Just like any other copy initialisation, the copy can be elided. This probably happens in your case, so the copy constructor is not actually called. Still, (again, just like with any other copy elision), it must be available.

Comment: OK, then why copy constructor is not called if I make it public?

Comment: @axe because of copy elision.

Comment: Thanks. But it's strange anyway. It could call directly the constructor like X x(1). I don't see reason of doing copy construction here.

Comment: @axe It is due to the different semantics of `T t(x)` and `T t = x;`. See more on that [here](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/036.htm).

Comment: You could also use C++11 uniform initialization syntax X x{1};

Answer (score 2):

you are trying to initialize a value to the class object here which calls the copy-constructor.

```
int main()
{
    X x = 1; 
}
```

change the code to

```
X x(1);
```